# why it display same data in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-contacts

**why it  display same data in recyclerview**

> i m trying to fetch all contacts and list it in recyclervie but it display same contact (MEANS: if contacts got 50 then it will display one contact 50 times)

```
private void displayContacts() {
    List<ContactsModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<ContactsModel>();
    ContactsModel data = new ContactsModel();

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                    cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    data.set_id(id);
                    data.setName(name);
                    data.setNumber(phoneNo);

                    Log.e("test", "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo);
                }

                pCur.close();
            } arrayList.add(data);
        }
    }
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(arrayList, getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


cur.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  I have made some changes:

```
    private void displayContacts() {

      String name_check="start";
List<ContactsModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<ContactsModel>();
ContactsModel data = new ContactsModel();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
final Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        do{
        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{id}, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                 String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                if(name check.equals(name)){
            name_check = name;
                       data.set_id(id);
                       data.setName(name);
                        data.setNumber(phoneNo);

                        Log.e("test", "Name: " + name + ", Phone No: " + phoneNo);
                        arrayList.add(data);
                 } 
            }

            pCur.close();
        }
     } while(cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
adapter = new ContactAdapter(arrayList, getApplicationContext());
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


     cur.close();
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the Ans But i have solved it before but now i want all contacts with no duplications

Comment: You can put a simple if condition.  For this declare a variable for store number fetch in each loop and initialize it with newly fetch number after satisfying conditions and also add data in array list after condition true.

Comment: @beginner I have updated my answer according your requirements look at this once again.